# how to solve a system of differential equation numerically

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

i want a solution for h1,h2,h3 and for ceta 1,2,3
 and plot h1,h2,h3 vs sigma1
this is the code in the image [image]

```
system = {Subscript[\[Theta], 1]'[\[Tau]] == 
   Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] - .036 Subscript[h, 2][\[Tau]]^2 + 
    10^-4/Subscript[h, 1][\[Tau]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 1][\[Tau]]],
   Subscript[h, 1]'[\[Tau]] == -10^-3 Subscript[h, 1][\[Tau]] + 
    10^-4 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 1][\[Tau]]], 
  Subscript[\[Theta], 2]'[\[Tau]] == 
   0.12375 Subscript[h, 2][\[Tau]]^2 - .857 Subscript[h, 
      1][\[Tau]]^2 - 1.0417 (10^-3) + (
    5 (10^-4) Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 2][\[Tau]]])/
    Subscript[h, 2][\[Tau]], 
  Subscript[h, 2]'[\[Tau]] == -10^-3 Subscript[h, 2][\[Tau]] + 
    5 (10^-4) Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 2][\[Tau]]], 
  Subscript[\[Theta], 
     3]'[\[Tau]] == -4.6296 (10^-3) Subscript[h, 1][\[Tau]]^2 + 
    1.04167 (10^-3) Subscript[h, 2][\[Tau]]^2 + .0125 Subscript[h, 
      3][\[Tau]]^2 + 
    2 (10^-4) + (2.5 (10^-3))/
     Subscript[h, 3][\[Tau]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 3][\[Tau]]], 
  Subscript[h, 3]'[\[Tau]] == 
   10^-3 Subscript[h, 3][\[Tau]] + 
    2.5 (10^-3) Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 3][\[Tau]]]}
```

i can't write the code in question

Comment: Check out `NDSolve`.

Comment: i checked it and i can use it but it give me error and i can't plot h1 vs sigma1

Comment: i have the code but i can't write it in the question so i upload the image-Chris K

Comment: Mohamed Khalid, welcome on Mathematica.StackExchange. Please, help other user to help you by: 1. posting the code that you have tried in `InputForm` so that it can be easily copied and manipulated. 2. post the name of any error message you have encountered or copy the whole message.

Comment: ok i post the code in the question

Comment: i can't understand BCs

Comment: It's about initial conditions for the six functions in your system.

Comment: 'sol = NDSolve[{system, Subscript[h, 1][0] == 0.004, 
   Subscript[\[Theta], 1][0] == 0, Subscript[h, 2][0] == 0.004, 
   Subscript[\[Theta], 2][0] == 0, Subscript[h, 3][0] == 0.004, 
   Subscript[\[Theta], 3][0] == 0}, {Subscript[h, 1], 
   Subscript[\[Theta], 1], Subscript[h, 2], Subscript[\[Theta], 2], 
   Subscript[h, 3], Subscript[\[Theta], 3]}, {\[Tau], 0, 1500}]'

Answer (score 3):

The system is expected in a single list, just like this:

```
system = {Subscript[θ, 1]'[τ] == 
   Subscript[σ, 1] - .036 Subscript[h, 2][τ]^2 + 
    10^-4/Subscript[h, 1][τ] Cos[Subscript[θ, 1][τ]],
   Subscript[h, 1]'[τ] == -10^-3 Subscript[h, 1][τ] + 
    10^-4 Sin[Subscript[θ, 1][τ]], 
  Subscript[θ, 2]'[τ] == 
   0.12375 Subscript[h, 2][τ]^2 - .857 Subscript[h, 
        1][τ]^2 - 
    1.0417 (10^-3) + (5 (10^-4) Cos[Subscript[θ, 2][τ]])/
     Subscript[h, 2][τ], 
  Subscript[h, 2]'[τ] == -10^-3 Subscript[h, 2][τ] + 
    5 (10^-4) Sin[Subscript[θ, 2][τ]], 
  Subscript[θ, 
      3]'[τ] == -4.6296 (10^-3) Subscript[h, 1][τ]^2 + 
    1.04167 (10^-3) Subscript[h, 2][τ]^2 + .0125 Subscript[h, 
        3][τ]^2 + 
    2 (10^-4) + (2.5 (10^-3))/Subscript[h, 3][τ] Cos[
      Subscript[θ, 3][τ]], 
  Subscript[h, 3]'[τ] == 
   10^-3 Subscript[h, 3][τ] + 
    2.5 (10^-3) Sin[Subscript[θ, 3][τ]],
  Subscript[h, 1][0] == 0.004,
  Subscript[θ, 1][0] == 0,
  Subscript[h, 2][0] == 0.004,
  Subscript[θ, 2][0] == 0,
  Subscript[h, 3][0] == 0.004,
  Subscript[θ, 3][0] == 0
  }
```

When calling

```
sol = NDSolve[
  system, {Subscript[h, 1], Subscript[θ, 1], Subscript[h, 2], 
   Subscript[θ, 2], Subscript[h, 3], 
   Subscript[θ, 3]}, {τ, 0, 1500}]
```

Mathematica complains that the system does not evaluate to numerical values at the initial time; the reason is the parameter $\sigma_1$.

The solution is to use `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  system, {Subscript[h, 1], Subscript[θ, 1], Subscript[h, 2], 
   Subscript[θ, 2], Subscript[h, 3], 
   Subscript[θ, 3]}, {τ, 0, 1500}, Subscript[σ, 1]]
```

For example, `sol[2]` returns the solutions for $\sigma_1 = 2$.

A plot of $h_1$ vs. $\sigma_1$ can obtained with

```
Plot3D[sol[s][[1]][τ], {τ, 0, 1500}, {s, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

Unfortunately, it looks really noisy...

Comment: ok i need to plot h1 vs sigma1

Comment: i don't understand the plot i need it in 2d because i need a relation between h1 vs sigma1 , h2 vs sigma1 and h3 vs sigma1

Comment: h1 is a function of tau and sigma1, that's why I used `Plot3D`.

Comment: is it work if i put a range for tau from 0 to 1500 and plot h1 vs sigma1 with a range for sigma1 from -0.008 to 0.008 to get arelation between h1 and sigma1 only

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you aim at. Maybe you'd like to plot `h1[1500]` vs. sigma1?

Comment: ok i get it thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome!